# how to add columns iteratively for recoding with semi-modified names

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, apply, purrr

I would use this dataset as an example

```
BEZ <- c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B")
var <- c("B","B","B","B","B","B","B")
bar <- c("B","B","B","B","B","B","B")

Bez1 <- c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B")
var1 <- c("B","B","B","B","B","B","B")
bar1 <- c("B","B","B","B","B","B","B")

dat <- data.frame(BEZ, var, bar, Bez1, var1, bar1)
```

the tricky thing that I would like to do is use a method (loops, map(), apply(), dplyr functions, and so on) to create aside the already existing new column where based on the respective row value is converted into a number.

**Excepeted result**

```
BEZ  BEZ_num  var  var_num  bar  bar_num  Bez1  BEZ1_num    var1  var1_num     bar1   bar1_num
  A     0       B   1        B    1         A       0         B       1          B       1
  A     0       B   1        B    1         A       0         B       1          B       1
  A     0       B   1        C    2         A       0         B       1          A       0
  A     0       B   1        B    1         A       0         C       2          B       1
  B     1       B   1        B    1         B       1         C       2          C       2
  B     1       B   1        B    1         A       0         B       1          B       1
  B     1       B   1        B    1         A       0         B       1          B       1
```

This is more or less the idea I would like to hit. Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: Is bar column correct in your data frame and in the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `factor`

```
library(dplyr)
 dat %>%
   mutate(across(everything(), ~ as.integer(factor(.x))-1, .names = "{.col}_num"))
```

-output

```
BEZ var bar Bez1 var1 bar1 BEZ_num var_num bar_num Bez1_num var1_num bar1_num
1   A   B   B    A    B    B       0       0       0        0        0        0
2   A   B   B    A    B    B       0       0       0        0        0        0
3   A   B   B    A    B    B       0       0       0        0        0        0
4   A   B   B    A    B    B       0       0       0        0        0        0
5   B   B   B    B    B    B       1       0       0        1        0        0
6   B   B   B    B    B    B       1       0       0        1        0        0
7   B   B   B    B    B    B       1       0       0        1        0        0
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a `for` loop in base R:

```r
dat2 <- dat[, 1, drop = FALSE]
for (col in names(dat)) {
  dat2[[col]] <- dat[[col]]
  dat2[[paste0(col, "_num")]] <- match(dat[[col]], LETTERS) - 1
}

dat2
#   BEZ BEZ_num var var_num bar bar_num Bez1 Bez1_num var1 var1_num bar1 bar1_num
# 1   A       0   B       1   B       1    A        0    B        1    B        1
# 2   A       0   B       1   B       1    A        0    B        1    B        1
# 3   A       0   B       1   B       1    A        0    B        1    B        1
# 4   A       0   B       1   B       1    A        0    B        1    B        1
# 5   B       1   B       1   B       1    B        1    B        1    B        1
# 6   B       1   B       1   B       1    B        1    B        1    B        1
# 7   B       1   B       1   B       1    B        1    B        1    B        1
```

Or a (slightly convoluted) approach using `dplyr::across()`:

```r
library(dplyr)

dat %>% 
  mutate(
    across(BEZ:bar1, list(TMP = identity, num = \(x) match(x, LETTERS) - 1)),
    .keep = "unused"
  ) %>% 
  rename_with(\(x) gsub("_TMP$", "", x))
# same output as above
```

Or finally, if you don't care about the order of the output columns, you could also use `dplyr::across()` with the `.names` argument:

```r
dat %>% 
  mutate(across(
    BEZ:bar1, 
    \(x) match(x, LETTERS) - 1,
    .names = "{.col}_num"
  ))
#   BEZ var bar Bez1 var1 bar1 BEZ_num var_num bar_num Bez1_num var1_num bar1_num
# 1   A   B   B    A    B    B       0       1       1        0        1        1
# 2   A   B   B    A    B    B       0       1       1        0        1        1
# 3   A   B   B    A    B    B       0       1       1        0        1        1
# 4   A   B   B    A    B    B       0       1       1        0        1        1
# 5   B   B   B    B    B    B       1       1       1        1        1        1
# 6   B   B   B    B    B    B       1       1       1        1        1        1
# 7   B   B   B    B    B    B       1       1       1        1        1        1
```

Comment: ok, that you so much. Actually, I should transfer this to the dataset where in place of a letter I have more complicated factors. That was just the simplest idea to explain what I wanted to do. Would you like me to exchange the dataset with an example closer to my case?

Comment: @alias yes, and also make clear how the values should be translated into the `*_num` columns.

Answer (score 2):

See in the comments. The provided data frame and the expected output do not match. But I think we could use `mutate(across..)` with the `.names argument` combined with `case_when`:

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~case_when(
    . == "A" ~ "0",
    . == "B" ~ "1",
    . == "C" ~ "2"), .names = "{col}_num"))
```

```
 BEZ var bar Bez1 var1 bar1 BEZ_num var_num bar_num Bez1_num var1_num bar1_num
1   A   B   B    A    B    B       0       1       1        0        1        1
2   A   B   B    A    B    B       0       1       1        0        1        1
3   A   B   B    A    B    B       0       1       1        0        1        1
4   A   B   B    A    B    B       0       1       1        0        1        1
5   B   B   B    B    B    B       1       1       1        1        1        1
6   B   B   B    B    B    B       1       1       1        1        1        1
7   B   B   B    B    B    B       1       1       1        1        1        1
```

Answer (score 1):

To add two further options:

With dplyr v.1.1.0 we can use `consecutive_id()`:

```r
library(dplyr) # v.1.1.0

dat %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(),
                ~ consecutive_id(.x)-1,
                .names = "{.col}_num"))

#>   BEZ var bar Bez1 var1 bar1 BEZ_num var_num bar_num Bez1_num var1_num bar1_num
#> 1   A   B   B    A    B    B       0       0       0        0        0        0
#> 2   A   B   B    A    B    B       0       0       0        0        0        0
#> 3   A   B   B    A    B    B       0       0       0        0        0        0
#> 4   A   B   B    A    B    B       0       0       0        0        0        0
#> 5   B   B   B    B    B    B       1       0       0        1        0        0
#> 6   B   B   B    B    B    B       1       0       0        1        0        0
#> 7   B   B   B    B    B    B       1       0       0        1        0        0
```

Similar we could use `data.table::rleid()`:

```r
dat %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(),
                ~ data.table::rleid(.x)-1,
                .names = "{.col}_num"))

#>   BEZ var bar Bez1 var1 bar1 BEZ_num var_num bar_num Bez1_num var1_num bar1_num
#> 1   A   B   B    A    B    B       0       0       0        0        0        0
#> 2   A   B   B    A    B    B       0       0       0        0        0        0
#> 3   A   B   B    A    B    B       0       0       0        0        0        0
#> 4   A   B   B    A    B    B       0       0       0        0        0        0
#> 5   B   B   B    B    B    B       1       0       0        1        0        0
#> 6   B   B   B    B    B    B       1       0       0        1        0        0
#> 7   B   B   B    B    B    B       1       0       0        1        0        0
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>